# Install Java using CMD script

Tags: java, installation, cmd

I am writing an application using Java and I want to send it to the customer. But he doesn't have Java on his computer (OS Win XP). I want to automate the installation using command shell scripting. Is it possible?

Comment: With a script almost everything is possible. Try some installation packs like IzPack or Launch4J

Comment: It will be better if you bundle the JRE along with your application. I use Launch4J for that purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `/s` option in JRE installer (see [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml)), so basically you can.
However, you will have to somehow download JRE to client's workstation. I suggest using [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for this.

However, you can also use java-to-exe wrappers - [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) for example can automagically download JRE for you if it is not installed.

Comment: I might suggest downloading the JRE and packaging it up with your Java application in a self extracting executable(.exe) that the customer can just run. Use a program such as 7-Zip to turn a compressed(.zip) archive into an executable then have the executable extract the JRE to \temp and execute the JRE installer with the /s option mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it on a bat file and ship a folder with an embeddable JVM, nevertheless I found using NSIS very effective for shipping swing APPS.

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

I'm not sure but I think you can also build the kind of installer you want.

Answer (score 0):

Java supports automated/silent command line install on PCs. See [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml)

You can also probably make use of batch scripts to automate some tasks...

[Batch Files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Type "/?" parameter for the installation exe in console in the folder were installer relies.

`C:\TEMP>jdk-7u4-windows-x64.exe /?`

There you see shortly parameter reference. /passive & /quiet are probably what you need, create a install.cmd with something like

```
cls
C:\TEMP>jdk-7u4-windows-x64.exe /quiet
echo installation complete
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following batch. I had a little trouble understanding the parameteres but finally this worked for me and without installing sponsor toolbars.

```
"@echo off 
copy "JavaSetup8u111.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\downloads\JavaSetup8u111.exe"
CD\
CD "%USERPROFILE%\downloads\"

start /B /WAIT JavaSetup8u111.exe /s SPONSORS=0
```